# What are the sqlite equivalents of MySQL's INTERVAL and UTC_TIMESTAMP?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

What are the sqlite equivalents of `INTERVAL` and `UTC_TIMESTAMP`? For example, imagine you were "porting" the following SQL from MySQL to sqlite:

```
SELECT mumble
  FROM blah
 WHERE blah.heart_beat_time > utc_timestamp() - INTERVAL 600 SECOND;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`datetime('now')` provides you the current date and time in UTC, so is the SQLite equivalent of MySQL's `UTC_TIMESTAMP()`.

It may also be useful to know that given a date and time string, `datetime` can convert it from localtime into UTC, using `datetime('2011-09-25 18:18', 'utc')`.

You can also use the `datetime()` function to apply modifiers such as '+1 day', 'start of month', '- 10 years' and many more.

Therefore, your example would look like this in SQLite:

```
SELECT mumble
  FROM blah
 WHERE blah.heart_beat_time > datetime('now', '-600 seconds');
```

You can find more of the modifiers on the [SQLite Date and Time Functions page](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: according to those docs, 'now' is already in 'utc' and adding 'utc' actually assumes the time is in local time (so adds/removes N hours), so I think that should be `datetime('now', '-600 seconds')`

Comment: @JacobGabrielson you are totally right. It was very late and my brain was fried from trying to fix a bug where everything was out by an hour (can be so many things when you're in the UK in summer!)  Fixed!

Answer (score 2):

There's no native timestamp support in sqlite.

I've used plain old (64-bit) integers as timestamps, representing either micro- or milliseconds since an epoch.

Therefore, assuming milliseconds:

```
SELECT mumble
  FROM blah
WHERE blah.heart_beat_time_millis > ? - 600*1000;
```

and bind system time in milliseconds to the first param.

Answer (score 1):

there is LOCAL_TIMESTAMP in SQLite, but it's GMT.