# Laravel/Eloquent - 15 Second Interval between timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Trying to prevent users from posting comments too quickly, so using a 15 second interval is the plan.

This query isn't working to see if a comment was made in the last 15 seconds though. What am I doing wrong?

Table:

```
 id  |      comment    |     created_at      |
==============================================
 2   |   blah casd     | 2013-06-20 18:14:17 |
```

However, I can't quite get it to work with Eloquent

```
    //are they commenting too fast?
    $protection = DB::table('comments')
       ->where('user_id', '=', $userid)
       ->where('created_at', '<', '(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 SECOND)')
       ->get();

    if(!empty($protection)) {
         return Redirect::back()->with_message('Please wait 15 seconds between comments.', 'error'); 
    }
```

Comment: If you're using Laravel 4, then I suggest that you make use of Carbon. Simply add the Provider to the list, as well as the alias in `app/config/app.php`. More about Carbon here: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

Comment: unfortunately I am working with L3

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try replacing

```
->where('created_at', '<', '(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 SECOND)')
```

with

```
->where('created_at', '<', DB::raw('NOW() + INTERVAL 15 SECOND)')
```

I hope this can be of some help.

Comment: This wasn't working for me. but this does: 
    where('last_update', '<', DB::raw('DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)') )

Comment: This only works using MySQL driver. For SQLite you have to use `datetime` function, see [corresponding SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7547245/570503).

Comment: FYI I think there's a syntax issue here, that last apostrophe should be moved to the left one char.

`->where('created_at', '<', DB::raw('NOW() + INTERVAL 15 SECOND'))`

Answer (score 3):

The comma is incorrect. You should be ADDING the interval:

```
NOW() + INTERVAL 15 SECOND
```

or subtracting, if you change it to a `>` comparison...

Comment: Hey I tried this and it still does not work correctly. Could it be a problem with different timestamps?